# Is it possible to connect to a specific host using WebRTC?

Tags: javascript, html, ip, webrtc

I'm trying to understand the WebRTC API, and although it appears that in the SDP blobs (otherwise known as RTCSessionDescription) that there is a field for the IP address of the connecting host, there is no API to set this from the JS.

Is it possible to connect to a specific host by their IP address?

Comment: It's been long since you asked the question. Did you find any solution that worked? Please share if you did

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can connect to a specific host because you can edit the SDP blob before inject it into the browser.
But the SDP has many other fields aside from the IP address.
You should know that the SDP should come from the other party with the right ICE user/pass and candidates, with the right keys for encode the stream, so that the other party can establish a connection with you.